# How can I add roads or conver to mesh?

Tags: blender-osm

I have selected road path. This road path is export from openstreetmap.org.
I have problem with add my road image here. If I added image like as on right side, nothing happens, but I can change color.

How can I resolved this?

[image]

Comment: you are probably in a view that doesn't show the textures. check this page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html

Comment: Your tags are internal render. That doesn't exist in the version you're using. Don't get me wrong, but these are very beginner issues. Really, not meant offensively, but consider spending a few hours testing and learning the basics. Also: You're not in rendered view, press Z and choose rendered from the pie menu.

Comment: Hi Frederik, I know this is begginer issues but I have tried really a lot of hours and still is the same. I have rendered view. Check new picture above.

Comment: I got problem. Problem was scale must be 100 instead of 1, and also rotation...

Comment: If you have an answer which solves your issue, please add it in the answer box below.